# Commutativity characterization?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $R$ be a ring (*not* necessarily unital) and for any $x\in R$ there is an integer $n \geq 2$ s.t. $x=x^2+\cdots+x^n.$ Does it imply that $R$ is commutative?

Comment: could you characterize all not necessarily unital rings generated by one variable that satisfies your condition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many of these questions are particular cases of the following general [theorem of Herstein](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2372554?uid=3738920&uid=2129&uid=2134&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21102167134987):

> If $R$ is a ring with center $Z$ and for every $a\in R$ there exists a polynomial $p_a\in\mathbb Z[X]$ such that $a^2p_a(a)-a\in Z$, then $R$ is commutative.

In your case just take $p_a(X)=1+X+\cdots+X^{n-2}$ for each $a\in R$ and conclude that $R$ is commutative.

Comment: Dear @YACP thank you, that's a very powerful result, good to know it.

Comment: When is the hypothesis of this theorem ever satisfied in practice?